# Сохранение позиции после окончания катсцены сделанной в Timeline

Tags: c#, unity3d, position, timeline

Открывается сцена,сразу идёт катсцена(сделана с помощью Timeline),когда она закончится персонаж должен остаться на том же месте где был в конце катсцены,а не телепортироваться туда где он был в начале потому,что после катсцена сразу начинается геймплей.

Comment: Если я правильно всё понял, то в чём проблема изначально поставить персонажа туда, где он должен быть в конце кат-сцены?

Comment: Мой персонаж должен пройти из точка А в точку В если я поставлю его сразу в точку В то идти ему никуда не надо будит,но это потеря для меня потому,что не будет анимации,а она очень нужна.